# Identify project's version using setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

I'm trying to build wheels for multiple projects that support different python versions. I can't just use "python bdist_wheel" because it will build the wheels for python 2.

So, is there an elegant way to identify project's supported python versions using setup.py?

If something will be need to be added to setup.py, it's ok.

Comment: is this what youre thinking about?   https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/

Comment: hmm... I guess it is.. Post it as a solution

Comment: Are you talking about the project version or the Python version? The former is what is fed in `version` argument in `setup` function, the latter can be specified via `python_requires` arg if you're using `setuptools` (this is the implementation of the [Requires-Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/#requires-python) field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what youre thinking about?
https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/

## Ways single-sourcing the package version

> 1: [image]
>
> 2: [image]
>
> 3: [image]
>
> 4: [image]
>
> 5: [image]
>
> 6: [image]
>
> 7: [image]